# Do I have to rewrite all overloaded operators in a subclass which were overloaded in the superclass in matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop, operator-overloading

I have a superclass

```
classdef superclass
properties
    a
    b
methods
% constructor
function obj = superclass(a,b)
    obj.a = a;
    obj.b = b;
end
... some code...
function c = plus(obj1,obj2)
    c = superclass(obj1.a+obj2.b,obj1.b)
end
```

(There is a lot of type checking and error throwing but this is the gist of it). This class has almost all of the operators are overloaded like this. Those which are not, throw an error. Now I have derived another class from this which adds some properties.

```
classdef subclass < superclass
properties
    p
    q
methods
... constructor and such...
end
```

Now when I do any operation on this class like adding it will return an object of the superclass (because of my overloaded plus function). The only way I see to fix this is overload all of those functions once again. That is tedious, is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you have your subclass just use `a` and `b` as well? What is different about `p` and `q`

Comment: I have subclasses because `p` and `q` parameters are one level of abstraction over `a` and `b`. So I can have subclass2 which can add `x` and `z` and does not use `p` and `q`.

edit: Just to clarify operations performed on `x` and `z` are completely different than operations performed on `p` and `q`.

Comment: well, if the operations on `p` and `q` are "completely different" than those on `a` and `b`, then *of course* you'd have to overload all the operators! Put differently, if `p` and `q` add specific behavior to `a` and `b`, then MATLAB has to know those specifics.